# URL mapping [Code igniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a test wallpapers app to learn the CodeIgniter framework.

How to achieve this:

" When I enter wallpapers.example.com , instead of redirecting to full link, home page should open at  wallpapers.example.com , want to exclude "/earthplanet/index.php/" thing from url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write this into your .htaccess file to redirect to 
subdomain/index.php/whatever_your_url_is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /earthplanet/index.php/$1 [L]
```

And FYI you should use the pretty URL's Codeigniter offers you:

```
http://wallpapers.studentbro.com/earthplanet/index.php/freewallpapers?wallis=Nature%20Wallpapers
```

should be:

```
http://wallpapers.studentbro.com/earthplanet/index.php/freewallpapers/Nature/Wallpapers
```

Comment: and in which directory,  I should place this .htaccess file? in application directory or where?

Comment: in the /earthplanet directory (where /application /system etc.. are)

Comment: You must also configure apache to allow rewriting url's by uncommenting this line: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in httpd.conf